# How to find the kth element of an 'infinite' Foldable structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, infinite, fold, foldable

I'd like to define a function, `safeIndex` that works on `Foldable` types

```
safeIndex :: (Foldable t, Integral i) => t a -> i -> Maybe a
safeIndex = foldr step (const Nothing)
  where
    step :: Integral i => a -> (i -> Maybe a) -> i -> Maybe a
    step x f i = if i == 0
               then Just x
               else f (i - 1)
```

But it doesn't work for infinite lists. For `foldr` to stop in the middle, I think we have to determine whether it should stop only with the first argument of `step`, which seems impossible.

Is it possible to fix the function so that it works on infinite structures? If not, what typeclasses should we restrict `t` to?

Comment: Why do you use `forall` here?

Comment: Otherwise `step`'s explicit type signature won't compile. I enabled `ScopedTypeVariable` language extension :)

Comment: `safeIndex [1..] 3` outputs `Just 4`. However it will not work for infinite snoc lists, but it doesn't make sense for those to "index from the right" in the first place.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Actually I've made some silly errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the definition in the question description already works for infinite built-in list. It was some other mistakes that make me thought it couldn't ;) (See the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind taking on a dependency, the [`foldl` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.3.0) from Gabriel Gonzalez provides `index` and `genericIndex` folds which suit your purpose.

For example, you could write

```
safeIndex :: (Foldable f, Integral a) => a -> f b -> Maybe b
safeIndex = fold . genericIndex
```

Besides that, the code you posted seems to do what you intend.

EDIT: I spaced the "infinite lists" bit.

This will work for infinite lists, but I don't know that there's a sensible way to define it for all `Foldable`s.

```
safeIndex' :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
safeIndex' n = listToMaybe . foldr (.) id (replicate n (drop 1))
```

EDIT 2:

Scratch that, what you've got in the original post ought to work for any `Foldable`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a handy library, although it doesn't work for infinite lists.

Comment: Oh, my, you're right. I completely glazed over the bit about infinite lists. I'll edit in an uglier idea.